# Archiving files in a subdirecory

Tags: xml, powershell, compression

I am attempting to use Powershell to create archives of all *.xml files in a particular folder in a network directory (excluding any .zip files which may already exist in the sub directory). I need to loop through all sub directories and only zip up files where they exist and only the *.xml files should be contained in the zip within the sub directory - the zip needs to have the sub directory and the date in the name. I would also like any xml files removed from the sub directory once zipped.

The following is what I have so far:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression" )
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )

$directory = 'C:\some directory' 

$folderstozip = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -Filter *.xml -Exclude *.zip |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique

foreach ($folder in $folderstozip) { 
    $archive = $folder + ((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd')) + '.zip'

    If(Test-Path $archive) { Remove-Item $archive }

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($folder, $archive, 'Optimal', $false)
}
```

This is creating the zip file in the directory above and not in the sub directory where the xml files exist.
I also have not been able to figure out how to use the `Remove-Item` cmdlet correctly. `Remove-Item $folderstozip -Recurse -Filter *.xml` removes the entire directory and I just want the xml files deleted. It is also including any zip files which exists in the sub directory in the zip.

Is anyone able to assist please? Any help will be much appreciated!
Please do let me know if anything is unclear and if you require further info.

Thank you,
Kind Regards, 
LR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Just to put it out there, this is what I ended up with.
It does exactly what I need, excludes already zipped files from the new zips, writes details of the successful zips to a log file and also reads a list of directories to search through and zip from a text file.

Hopefully someone will find this useful :) It may not be as streamlined as a Powershell expert would code it, but i'm pretty happy with it!

Thanks!

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Script: Archiver.ps1
# Author: 
# Date: 31/01/2017
# Comments: .NET Framework 4.5 required - WMF 5.0 required i.e. powershell 5.0
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression" )
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )

$streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList "C:\archiver\includedirectories.txt"
$streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList "C:\archiver\archiverlogfile.txt", $true 

while($line = $streamReader.ReadLine())
{
     $directory = $line

     $folderstozip = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -Include *.xml, *.onx, *.xls, *.txt, *.xlsx, *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique 

    foreach ($folder in $folderstozip) 
    { 
        $archive = $folder + ((Get-Date).ToString('_yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm')) + '.zip' 

        If(Test-path $archive) {Remove-item $archive}

        $filestozip = Get-ChildItem $folder . -exclude *.zip

        Compress-Archive $filestozip $archive -CompressionLevel Fastest  

        Move-Item -Path $archive -Destination $folder

        $streamWriter.WriteLine(((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm - ')) + 'Zipped ' + $archive + ' to ' + $folder + ' successfully.') 

        Remove-Item $folder\* -Recurse -Include *.xml, *.onx, *.xls, *.txt, *.xlsx, *.csv   
    }
}
$streamReader.close()
$streamWriter.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as `Remove-Item`, try using the `-Include` switch instead of `-Filter` if you only want to delete files of a certain extension. Also your folder path needs a `\*` after it to indicate that you're looking at the contents of the folder and not the folder itself. I would change the line you mentioned to

```
Remove-Item $folderstozip\* -Recurse -Include *.xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much king3vbo - I have the remove-Item bit working now.

My script is however still putting the zip file in the parent directory (and not where the files exist) and is also not only including xml files in the zip.
Any ideas regarding these parts perhaps please?

Comment: Are you on PowerShell 5? If so, you could use Compress-Archive to do something like

`Get-ChildItem -Path D:\xmlfiles\*.xml | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "D:\archive\$archive.zip"`

Answer (score 0):

Is moving the zips after a viable option?

```
Move-Item -Path "$directory\$archive" -Destination $folder
```

Alternatively, I believe the problem is with this line:

```
$archive = $folder + ((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd')) + '.zip'
```

Print it out to ensure it contains what you think. Would have thought it would need to be something like:

```
$archive = $folder.FullName + "\" ((Get-Date).ToString(' yyyy-MM-dd')) + '.zip'
```

Comment: thank you gms0ulman - I changed the line to the below and it is now working perfectly:

 $archive = $folder + '\' + ((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')) + '.zip'
The move-item option would also have worked well.The only bit I am still struggling with is not including zip files which already exist in the source directory in the actual new zip - any ideas on this perhaps please?

Comment: Lots of forums suggest using the ZipArchive.CreateEntry method but I just cannot figure out how to use this correctly in Powershell. Apologies for all the questions on this but I am very new to Powershell!

Comment: If answer answers question, please mark as accepted!
I don't believe this is possible: it looks like the `CreateFromDirectory` method will include all files with no option to exclude. `Remove-Item` should be getting rid of the old zips before they are zipped; is that not happening? It may be that the script is running too fast; Add `Start-Sleep 5` after removing the item and before creating the zip. Check out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) for what the ZipFile class offers, and related classes (ZipArchive, ZipFileExtensions).

Comment: Hi, I still have some issues and it looks like I can only accept one answer.Remove-Item is removing the files which have been zipped up. Older zipped files should not be removed as this is a process which will run every week and we require the older zips to be kept as it is the archive of our old interface files. I have tried playing around with ZipFile, ZipArchive and ZipFileExtensions and cannot get it working. I will continue trying. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies, I notice now that the `Remove-Item` is referring to _today's_ archive.  How about using [ZipFileExtensions.CreateEntryFromFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx) as this allows you to specify which files you would like to archive?